# How about page numbers on the top of pages as well?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, user-interface

I was looking through the unanswered questions in Ask Ubuntu and after reading through some I was at the top of the page. In order to go to the page before or after it, I had to scroll down to the current page's bottom to click on the page number. Wouldn't it be easier if we had page number selectors on the top and bottom of the page?

Edit : Perhaps mentioning I'm using a netbook and it has a small screen would be useful to consider this question's relevance.

Answer (score 8):

## That would be awesome!

(Supporters upvote. Those who are against upvote the other option)

Answer (score -3):

## Nah! That does not improve navigation, so NO.

(Supporters upvote. Those who are against upvote the other option)

Comment: How many useful non-list questions have so many answers that they need pagination?

Comment: I was not referring to the page of a particular question. I was referring to the pages listing the questions themselves.