# How to proceed with a feature request?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

I have made a feature request recently in meta. You can find it at [How about page numbers on the top of pages as well?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3203/how-about-page-numbers-on-the-top-of-pages-as-well) .

Do I just leave it there or are there any specific steps that I should do in order to get the feature request approved or rejected?

If I am to leave it there, then how does acceptance or rejection of a feature request work out in meta?

Better still, when does a feature-request get accepted or rejected? Is there a threshold value for the number of upvotes or downvotes that it should receive?

Comment: I wonder how this question should be tagged so that is clear that it is about feature requests without being a feature request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just leave it there and hope it gets enough attention. As far as I know there is no special conditions for getting a requested feature accepted or rejected. It is all about presenting a good case that those in power happen to approve of. It may be easier to get attention for features that will affect the whole network on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). But it has been said [that Stack Exchange employees monitor metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118212/163868) across the network.

Acceptance and rejection of a feature request is handled by Stack Exchange employees. Feature requests can be tagged accord to their status by moderators, i.e. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).

Here are some general tips:

- As for any question, make sure the title is clear and that you present a clear case of what you are after. Screenshots and mockups are good ways to make your case even clearer.
- Describe how your feature request can be implemented.
- Provide arguments for why your feature request should be implemented.
- Provide arguments for how any problems the feature might case can be handled.
- If someone argues against you, then you should counter their arguments.
- Make sure to tag it properly, i.e. as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and some appropriate tag on what the feature request relates to.